# How do I initialize list.js after a dynamically-created list is rendered?

Tags: javascript

Sadly, `list.js` isn't filtering my list at all. I'm assuming it's because the elements are not in the DOM when the javascript is called.

```
  var render = function(list, arr){ 
    arr.forEach(function(coder){ 
      var context = { logo:coder.logo,
                      name:coder.displayName,
                    status:coder.status,
               status_icon:coder.status_icon,
                       url:coder.url};
      var html = template(context);
      $(list).append(html);
    })
    var options = { valueNames: [ 'name' ]  };
    var hackerList = new List('hacker-list', options);
  }
  ...
  render('#all',all);
  render('#offline', offline);
  render('#online', online);
```

You can see in the last two lines, where I am attempting to call the code after forEach is finished appending all the elements (handlebar templates). But that is not working for me either.

Here is the surrounding HTML.

```
<div class='container' id='main-list'>
  <div id='hacker-list' class="">
    <ul  class="row list" >
      <li id='_all' class="btn btn-default col-xs-4 arrow_box all">All</li>
      <li id='_online' class="btn btn-default col-xs-4 online">Online</li>
      <li id='_offline' class="btn btn-default col-xs-4 offline">Offline</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <input class="search" />
  <div class='panel' id="all"></div>
  <div class='panel' id="online"></div>
  <div class='panel' id="offline"></div>
</div>
<script src="http://listjs.com/no-cdn/list.js"></script>
```

Could it be that the last line in this code is the one that is firing too early?
Is this not a common problem? Doesn't seem so from searching through the questions...

Answer (score 0):

```
render('#all',all);
render('#offline', offline);
render('#online', online);
```

In this `all`, `offline`, and `online` are variables. Are they set somewhere? Most likely you have an error in your console saying they are not defined if you look.

Per the documentation http://www.listjs.com/docs the second argument is options and should contain an object. Is this how you have it setup?